# Python - Working with obj/stl files and 3d meshes

Tags: python, 3d, mesh

I've never worked with 3d objects in any capacity, and especially not in Python. I am currently working on a pet project where I have stl and obj files containing irregularly shaped objects. I would like to eventually be able to calculate the surface area of these objects, and also to be to find the circumference at various points along the object. I would also like to able to find the surface area between various circumferences.

I don't need an easy way to do this (I'm not sure how applicable something like blender would be, but I would like to avoid using anything that involves a GUI). This is more than anything an exercise, so even if it takes months, I would prefer to output code as opposed to just having the numbers.

Some of the things that I've found and have been playing with are

```
from stl import mesh
```

and also [MeshPy](https://documen.tician.de/meshpy/), which I've tried and failed to download properly.

If using Python is absolutely not recommended, I don't mind learning another language. I'm just really lost on where to start with this.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually the same problem two months ago. I was first started with 3D meshes and I had to create some routines to work with .stl files. In order to provide you a better response, could you provide me which are the specific utilities you're looking for?

There are several python packages that are capable to work with 3D meshes. The more popular ones are stl, vtk, openmesh and meshpy. You can use either one or another depending on your aim. Maybe the most complete is vtk, which has lots of classes and functionalities. However, if you come from a non-informatic  background (I'm physicist for instance), this package is object orientated so you may have problems at the beginning.

As said, It will be usefull if you can share the utilities you're looking for in order to give you a more accurate response.
Good luck!

Comment: I'm a little unclear in what you mean by utilities? My main purpose with the project is to be able to calculate "circumferences" at various points along the object, and then to be able to calculate surface areas between these circumferences. So in my case I will be working with scans of bodies. I'd like to for instance be able to find the surface area of someone's upper leg by specifying a circumference at the top of the leg and at the knee. Things like that. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I don't know if it's going to be useful for you or not, but I recommend you to use numpy-stl package. I had actually a similar problem: I had to compute Willmore Flow of a given mesh, which is nothing else but a sum of the angles between circumscribed spheres. This package allows you to open a mesh (for instance a stl file) and with the function your_mesh.Points() you'll get all a list of 3x3 matrices corresponding to the three points (with it's three cordinates) of each face.

Comment: As said, this is something very basic and standard, but this simplicity also implies a better control over the functionalities you want to get. However, I understand by reading your post that you have time, so I encourage you to start from the mesh and try to build up your function from the very begging. I'm new at answering post , so I hope that this is useful for you.